# Le bootstrap starter template

Tags: css

I'm looking at [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html), and I see all these comments like:

```
Le styles
Le javascript
```

Q: Is that for the LESS framework, or are they just being French?

Comment: I was just about to ask this very same question. +1 :)

Comment: If StackOverflow wants people to ask questions, baby I got 'em!

Comment: It's a tired, overused joke that was never very funny to begin with.  http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/le 

Somebody tried to get rid of it but they stuck to their guns. https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4119

Comment: Thanks Sean!  That was an interesting diversion.  I left a comment on their github page.

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/4119

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but since they are just comments they must be French!

Comment: <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements --> commonly called FRENGLISH in Quebec ;)

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing whatsoever to do with LESS since comments in LESS code (just as in CSS) are ignored; i.e., they're just "being French" as you put it!

EDIT: Plus, the comments you're talking about are on the HTML page, which can't affect the imported files anyway :)